# Android in-app billing subscription verifying

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

I would like to verify subscription on my server, but I get invalid_grant error when I try to get access token.
I use that code in php on my server:

```
$refreshToken = '4/cTphJ...';
$clientId = '1234567.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$clientSecret = '';
$redirectUri = 'https://www.example.com/oauth2callback';

$ch = curl_init();

$url  = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=' . $clientId . '&client_secret=' . $clientSecret . '&code=' . $refreshToken . '&redirect_uri=' . $redirectUri);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

What can be wrong?

**Edit:**
When I generated the right code then I am not getting invalid_grant error anymore, but now I am getting error "This developer account does not own the application". My android application and new API Project in the Google Console are created with the same google account, so why I see that error?

Comment: I am not sure but i think there is some issue of permission on your server. Have you checked your auth token and user name and pass?

Comment: What do you mean? I Don't have any user name, password or auth token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my error. I called that url https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=...&client_id=... but my redirect_uri was wrong and then I got a wrong code.

My email in settings on the developer console was wrong.